# How is a struct of struct's memory arranged by default in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, memory, vector

If I want to define a `Matrix` class in C++, for OpenGL rendering for example, the way I like to do it, and which also seems the most convenient, is to first define a `Vector` class as such :

```cpp
class vec3 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    [ ... ]
}

class vec4 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double w;
    [ ... ]
}
```

Now, as far as I understand, the values   of `x, y, z{, w}` are supposed to be contiguous in memory when I create a vec{3|4} (right ???).

If I then create my matrix as such :

```cpp
class mat3 {
    vec3 _m[3];
    [ ... ]
}

class mat4 {
    vec4 _m[4];
    [ ... ]
}
```

Would the values of `x, y, z{, w}` of each vector in the matrix class ***always*** be next to one another in memory ? If I give the adress of the first element to OpenGL, which reads the next 16 values in memory (for a 4x4 matrix), would it read the 16 values of the matrix in order, or could some other information from elsewhere in the program get in the way ?

Edit (29/Nov./2019) : Fixed a typo

Comment: See [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). As well it is better idea to use de-facto standard library `OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)`, instead of inventing your own linear algebra lib. GLM is optimized with MMX/SSE/AVX SIMD instructions, matrix operation speed really does mater. Also check [learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/) resource, you can found this library usage example.

Comment: I would use it, it's just because it was an assignment for my course. We had to create our own basic linear algebra, and be able to use it in all our course's other assignments @VictorGubin

Comment: ok then, in this case better choose to define the vector as  `struct vec3 { float xyz[3];  constexpr vec(float x, float y, float x) : xyz( {x,y,z} ) noexcept {} float x() const noexcept { return xyz[0];} ... }` you can use templates exactly like  GLM doing it.

Comment: Also check C++ 11 [alignas specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Comment: The standard allows arbitrary padding, so technically this is implementation-defined. I don't know of any implementation that does something unexpected for your case though, so you should be fine by just adding a `static_assert(sizeof(vec3) == 3 * sizeof(double));`.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the values of x, y, z{, w} of each vector in the matrix class always be next to one another in memory ?

Probably not guaranteed to be so by the language, but probably will be contiguous in practice.

> would it read the 16 values of the matrix

The behaviour of indexing over members is undefined in C++. The API probably written in C which may have different rules through.

There is a data structure that you can iterate over and is guaranteed to have 16 adjacent elements: array of 16 doubles.

Comment: C has pretty much the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

The robust solution is to start with a `double[16]`. To the compiler, `&vec3::y` is just a way to express the offset of `y`, and you want that to be 1. You can achieve the same by writing

```
struct vec3 {
   double* base;
   double& x() { return *base; }
   double& y() { return *(base+1); }
   double& z() { return *(base+2); }
};
struct mat3 {
   double values[9];
   vec3 operator[](size_t s) { return vec3{values+3*s}; }
};
```

It's all inline, so the compiler can still calculate the offsets statically. There won't be a function call at runtime when you use `y()`.

Comment: Except in debug builds and when debugging which can be really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The standard allows arbitrary padding, so technically whether the members are contiguous in memory is implementation-defined. I don't know of any implementation that does something unexpected for your case though, so you should be fine by just adding a `static_assert(sizeof(vec3) == 3 * sizeof(double));`.

Similarly, accessing a bunch of members as if they were an array (i.e. via pointer arithmetic) in your code is undefined behavior by the standard, as there is no actual array object there. Now, if you give OpenGL this `struct` which has the values in the right places there should be no problem (because your compiler presumably doesn't touch the OpenGL code and the OpenGL only cares that the bytes are what they should be).

But note that this is only "fine" for the scope of the course I would say. For actual production code, these assumptions are too flimsy and a more robust (but possibly slightly less convenient) approach should be preferred.